# Logistic regression: plotting decision boundary from theta

Tags: python, numpy, logistic-regression

I have the following code:

```
x1 = np.random.randn(100)
y1 = np.random.randn(100) + 3
x2 = np.random.randn(100) + 3
y2 = np.random.randn(100)
plt.plot(x1, y1, "+", x2, y2, "x")
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

which results in the following image

[image]

I have implemented my own logistic regression, and this returns a theta, and I want to use this theta to plot the decision boundary, but I'm not sure how to do this.

```
X = np.matrix(np.vstack((np.hstack((x1,x2)), np.hstack((y1,y2)))).T)
X = np.concatenate((np.ones((X.shape[0], 1)), X), axis=1)
Y = np.matrix(1.0 * np.hstack((np.zeros(100), np.ones(100)))).T

learning_rate = 0.0001
iterations    = 3000
theta         = np.matrix([[0.5], [0.5], [0.5]])
theta = logistic_regression(theta, X, Y, learning_rate, iterations)
```

and this gives `theta` =

```
[[ 0.40377942]
 [ 0.53696461]
 [ 0.1398419 ]]
```

for example. How can I use this to plot the decision boundary?

Comment: Explain the meaning of the return values of your `logistic_regression` function.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser the theta values as seen in [this video](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/lecture/WuL1H/decision-boundary)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to plot θ<sup>T</sup>X = 0, where X is the vector containing (1, x, y).  That is, you want to plot the line defined by `theta[0] + theta[1]*x + theta[2]*y = 0`. Solve for y:

```
y = -(theta[0] + theta[1]*x)/theta[2]
```

So, something like:

```
theta = theta[:,0]  # Make theta a 1-d array.
x = np.linspace(-6, 6, 50)
y = -(theta[0] + theta[1]*x)/theta[2]
plt.plot(x, y)
```

Something doesn't look right, though, because you have `theta[1] > 0` and `theta[2] > 0`, which results in a line with a negative slope.

Comment: I literally just figured it out myself, then came here and saw what I did was correct! Adjusting the parameters like `learning_rate` results in a good decision boundary, so it definitely works :)